# How to improve MFC fprint writing performance?

Tags: visual-c++, printf

I’m writting an MFC GUI program that plots graphs in real time when it receives new data. It comes 30 data per second. I’m adding a new function where writing a text file using `fopen` and `fprint` every time it receives new data. So, it creates 30 new text files per a second.

Because of the writing function, the problem is that the program looks pause, not updating the graphs in real-time. when I turn off the writing function, it works well.

How can I resolve the problem?

I appreciate your help in advance. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you creating 30 new text files per second? You'll end up with thousands of files. Are you sure you want this? What's the approximate length of each o these texte files? Why not create a new file only every minute or so? Please elaborate your question and tell us more about that program.

Comment: None of your tags are relevant. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47826815/edit) your question accordingly.

Comment: If for EVERY data point (30 times a second), you do an Open, Write(Append?), Close, then it will definitely be SLOW.  Cache your data in RAM, then dump it at the end?  If it's too much data, possibly do multi-thread and keep your UI thread fast, and have the other thread (lower priority) dump the data to the file(s) but KEEP the file(s) opened.

Comment: "_So, it creates 30 new text files per a second._" - The file system is already the slowest memory of the computer. You are slowing it down even more by forcing frequent directory lookups. The more files you have, the slower these lookups will become. Do some profiling, I bet the bottleneck isn't `fprint` but `fopen`.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to a drive tends to be slow because of the OS/hardware.  There used to be this thing called a RAMDISK.  Basically a device driver that made a drive letter in ram.  After the files are written they could be copied to a new location hard drive or SSD location.  Opening and closing files take up operating system resources.  It's hard to know your programs design from your description...